# Seeing a straight line instead of a route on my google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Hi i am trying to achieve a google map app showing a directional route between two location markers.
My first marker/location is my device's current location and the second is taken from db through api.

The picture of the output is attached to this question.

Google map output

Here is my code.

HttpConnection.java class ->

```
    public class HttpConnection {
     String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    iStream));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            data = sb.toString();
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
//            Log.d("Exception while reading url", e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

DirectionsJSONParser.java class ->

```
    public class DirectionsJSONParser {

    /** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude */
    public List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>() ;
        JSONArray jRoutes = null;
        JSONArray jLegs = null;
        JSONArray jSteps = null;

        try {

            jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

            /** Traversing all routes */
            for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
                jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
                List path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                /** Traversing all legs */
                for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){
                    jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                    /** Traversing all steps */
                    for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                        String polyline = "";
                        polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        List list = decodePoly(polyline);

                        /** Traversing all points */
                        for(int l=0;l <list.size();l++){
                            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude) );
                            hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).longitude) );
                            path.add(hm);
                        }
                    }
                    routes.add(path);
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){
        }

        return routes;
    }

    /**
     * Method to decode polyline points
     * Courtesy : http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
     * */
    private List decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List poly = new ArrayList();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java class ->

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    ArrayList<LatLng> MarkerPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker1,mCurrLocationMarker2;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE = 1;
    String stringIMEI = "",stringLatitudeOrigin = "",stringLongitudeOrigin = "",
            stringLatitudeDest = "",stringLongitudeDest = "";

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
//        MultiDex.install(this);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        if (checkLocationPermission()){
            buildGoogleApiClient();
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
        }else {
            TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            stringIMEI = mngr.getDeviceId().toString();
        }
    }
    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        if (checkLocationPermission()) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    private String getUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {
        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;
        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;
/*       String waypoints = "waypoints=optimize:true|" + ANDHERI.latitude + "," + ANDHERI.longitude + "|"
              + JAGRUTI_NAGAR.latitude + "," + JAGRUTI_NAGAR.longitude + "|";
         Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";
        String mode = "mode=driving"; */
        String key = "key=mygoogleapikey";
        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin + "&"  + str_dest + "&"  + key;//+ waypoints + "&"
        // Output format
        String output = "json";
        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;
        return url;
    }
    /**
     * A method to download json data from url
     */

    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class FetchUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            String data = "";
            try {
                HttpConnection http = new HttpConnection();
                data = http.downloadUrl(url[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            new ParserTask().execute(result);
        }
    }
    /**
     * A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format
     */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {
        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {
            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;
            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                Log.d("ParserTask",jsonData[0].toString());
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();
                Log.d("ParserTask", parser.toString());
                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
                Log.d("ParserTask","Executing routes");
                Log.d("ParserTask",routes.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("ParserTask",e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }
        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
            // Traversing through all the routes
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                points = new ArrayList<>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);
                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for (int j = 0; j < MarkerPoints.size(); j++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }
                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(10);
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED);

                Log.d("onPostExecute","onPostExecute lineoptions decoded");
            }
            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            if(lineOptions != null) {
                mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
            }
            else {
                Log.d("onPostExecute","without Polylines drawn");
            }
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) { }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker1 != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker1.remove();
        }
        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        stringLatitudeOrigin = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        stringLongitudeOrigin = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
        mCurrLocationMarker1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Your device"));

        GetLocationVolleyRequest();
        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,13.0f));
        //stop location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) { }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Asking user if explanation is needed
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission was granted. Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }
                }else {
                    // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }
            case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE : {
                if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                    stringIMEI = mngr.getDeviceId().toString();
                }else {
                    // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
            // You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
        }
    }

    public void GetLocationVolleyRequest(){

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.LOCATIONAPI_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);

                            if (json.getString("success").equals("1")) {

                                stringLatitudeDest = json.getString("latitude");
                                stringLongitudeDest = json.getString("longitude");

                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Other Device -> Lat : "+stringLatitudeDest + " Lng : " +
                                        stringLongitudeDest,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                mCurrLocationMarker2 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(stringLatitudeDest),
                                        Double.parseDouble(stringLongitudeDest))).title("Other device"));

                                MarkerPoints.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(stringLatitudeOrigin),
                                        Double.parseDouble(stringLongitudeOrigin)));
                                MarkerPoints.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(stringLatitudeDest),
                                        Double.parseDouble(stringLongitudeDest)));

//                                 Instantiating the class PolylineOptions to plot polyline in the map
                                PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                                // Setting the color of the polyline
                                polylineOptions.color(Color.RED);
                                // Setting the width of the polyline
                                polylineOptions.width(10);
                                // Setting points of polyline
                                polylineOptions.addAll(MarkerPoints);
                                // Adding the polyline to the map
                                mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
                                // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured

                                if (MarkerPoints.size() >= 2) {
                                    LatLng origin = MarkerPoints.get(0);
                                    LatLng dest = MarkerPoints.get(1);
                                    // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                                    String url = getUrl(origin, dest);
                                    Log.d("onMapClick", url.toString());
                                    FetchUrl fetchUrl = new FetchUrl();
                                    // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                                    fetchUrl.execute(url);
                                    //move map camera
                                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(origin,14.0f));
                                }
                            }else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Could not Co-ordinates due to"+json.getString("error_msg"),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }catch (JSONException je){
                            je.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("imei",stringIMEI);
                params.put("latitude",stringLatitudeOrigin);
                params.put("longitude",stringLongitudeOrigin);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasn't getting any response to my android code from the google api url with `http://` so changed it to `https://` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

1 Get direction URL require to call Google Maps API

```
private String  getMapsApiDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest) {
   // Origin of route
 String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

 // Destination of route
 String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;        


 // Sensor enabled
 String sensor = "sensor=false";            

 // Building the parameters to the web service
 String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

 // Output format
 String output = "json";

 // Building the url to the web service
 String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;


 return url;

}
```

2. Do the URL call in background

```
  private class ReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void , String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String data = "";
        try {
            MapHttpConnection http = new MapHttpConnection();
            data = http.readUr(url[0]);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        new ParserTask().execute(result);
    }

    }
 public class MapHttpConnection {
  public String readUr(String mapsApiDirectionsUrl) throws IOException{
      String data = "";
      InputStream istream = null;
      HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
      try {
          URL url = new URL(mapsApiDirectionsUrl);
          urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          urlConnection.connect();
          istream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream));
          StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
          String line ="";
          while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
              sb.append(line);
          }
          data = sb.toString();
          br.close();


      }
      catch (Exception e) {
          Log.d("Exception while reading url", e.toString());
      } finally {
          istream.close();
          urlConnection.disconnect();
      }
      return data;

  }
}
```

3. Create Parser class to parse the data from JSON to List of pointes

```
  public class PathJSONParser {

public List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject) {
    List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>();
    JSONArray jRoutes = null;
    JSONArray jLegs = null;
    JSONArray jSteps = null;
    try {
        jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");
        for (int i=0 ; i < jRoutes.length() ; i ++) {
            jLegs = ((JSONObject) jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
            for(int j = 0 ; j < jLegs.length() ; j++) {
                jSteps = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");
                for(int k = 0 ; k < jSteps.length() ; k ++) {
                    String polyline = "";
                    polyline = (String) ((JSONObject) ((JSONObject) jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                    List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);
                    for(int l = 0 ; l < list.size() ; l ++){
                        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        hm.put("lat",
                                Double.toString(((LatLng) list.get(l)).latitude));
                        hm.put("lng",
                                Double.toString(((LatLng) list.get(l)).longitude));
                        path.add(hm);
                    }
                }
                routes.add(path);
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return routes;

}

private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
    List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }
    return poly;
}}
```

4. Do the parse using another Thread to expand performance

   ```
   private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer, 
    List<List<HashMap<String , String >>>> {
    @Override
     protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(
         String... jsonData) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     JSONObject jObject;
     List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;
     try {
         jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
         PathJSONParser parser = new PathJSONParser();
         routes = parser.parse(jObject);


     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
        return routes;
    }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes) {
     ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
     PolylineOptions polyLineOptions = null;

     // traversing through routes
     for (int i = 0; i < routes.size(); i++) {
         points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
         polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
         List<HashMap<String, String>> path = routes.get(i);

         for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
             HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

             double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
             double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
             LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

             points.add(position);
         }

         polyLineOptions.addAll(points);
         polyLineOptions.width(4);
         polyLineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
     }

     googleMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);

    }}
   ```

5 When you want to get the path of two point

```
String url = getMapsApiDirectionsUrl(latlngOne, latlngTwo);                    
    ReadTask downloadTask = new ReadTask();       
    // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
    downloadTask.execute(url);
```

To calculate distance between points

```
float[] results = new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(latLongA.latitude, latLongB.longitude,
                         latLongB.latitude, latLongB.longitude,
                         results);
```

*Note : Results will be in meters*

Comment: thank you for your code..My code looks almost similar to your code except the part of getting the second location from api..Thank you for the distance calculation code but i only need to show the route for the timing. :)

Comment: tried your code getting error as mentioned below. 
    java.lang.NullPointerException: PolylineOptions cannot be null.

Comment: hey i have two markers/locations but the routes.size() is zero.   What should i do ??

Comment: i executed the url on browser (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=19.1079,72.8793&destination=19.1079,72.8793&key=mykey) and got big response. But getting null value when debugging the android code.

Comment: hey thanks for your help..found the solution and now its working